# remove specific values from each element of a nested list

Tags: r, purrr, nested-lists

I have a nested list, like so:

```
nested.list <- list(c(46270L, 103154L, 159944L, 193405L, 199925L), c(24049L, 
  30454L, 55710L, 106407L, 122059L, 174131L), c(14520L, 46270L, 
  153636L, 188626L, 199925L), c(8150L, 24049L, 27321L, 30461L, 
  33513L, 55710L, 58933L, 71342L, 103154L, 122059L, 159920L, 169516L, 
  174131L), c(19195L, 71333L, 122059L, 137645L, 153636L, 183740L, 
  195065L, 199925L), c(14520L, 60368L, 80939L, 82381L, 95070L, 
  103172L, 106379L, 147215L, 166353L, 199925L), c(30461L, 68324L, 
  75981L, 77674L, 106407L, 120284L), c(24029L, 72751L, 103154L, 
  120284L, 142359L))

> nested.list
[[1]]
[1]  46270 103154 159944 193405 199925

[[2]]
[1]  24049  30454  55710 106407 122059 174131

[[3]]
[1]  14520  46270 153636 188626 199925

[[4]]
 [1]   8150  24049  27321  30461  33513  55710  58933  71342 103154 122059 159920 169516 174131

[[5]]
[1]  19195  71333 122059 137645 153636 183740 195065 199925

[[6]]
 [1]  14520  60368  80939  82381  95070 103172 106379 147215 166353 199925

[[7]]
[1]  30461  68324  75981  77674 106407 120284

[[8]]
[1]  24029  72751 103154 120284 142359
```

Within each list, I only want to keep these numbers. (edited to include a more illustrative list).

```
target.values <- c(24029, 33513, 60368, 106407, 147215, 153636, 159920, 193405)
```

I tried `purrr::keep(.x = nested.list, .p = function(x){all(x %in% target.values)})`, but clearly I'm missing something about how this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `intersect`:

```
lapply(nested.list,intersect, target.values)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just because an object is called `nested.list`, it does necessarily *is* a nested list. You object is a list of *vectors*, and we don't need special packages:

```r
lapply(nested.list, function(z) z[z %in% target.values])
```

Comment: Indeed. If it was actually nested, then you'd need to search recursively - `rapply(nested.list, \(z) z[z %in% target.values], how="list")`

Answer (score 3):

You can vectorize over the comparison for a bit of a speedup for a list with a large number of vectors.

```
f6 <- function(x, target) {
  u <- unlist(x)
  i <- which(u %in% target)
  setNames(split(u[i], rep(as.factor(1:length(x)), lengths(x))[i]), names(x))
}
```

Using @ThomasIsCoding's benchmark:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f1 = f1(),
  f2 = f2(),
  f6 = f6(nested.list, target.values),
  unit = "relative",
  check = "equivalent"
)
#> Unit: relative
#>  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>    f1 2.106476 1.893394 2.113900 1.895352 1.883364 3.380201   100
#>    f2 6.219841 5.649225 6.325568 5.629023 5.760277 6.345773   100
#>    f6 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a benchmarking for different implementations

```
set.seed(0)
nested.list <- replicate(1000, sample.int(100, sample.int(100, 1)))
target.values <- sample.int(100, 50)

f1 <- function() {
    lapply(nested.list, \(x) x[x %in% target.values])
}

f2 <- function() {
    lapply(nested.list, intersect, target.values)
}

f3 <- function() {
    Map(intersect, nested.list, list(target.values))
}

f4 <- function() {
    rapply(nested.list, \(z) z[z %in% target.values], how = "list")
}

f5 <- function() {
    map(nested.list, keep, \(x) x %in% target.values)
}

microbenchmark(
    f1 = f1(),
    f2 = f2(),
    f3 = f3(),
    f4 = f4(),
    f5 = f5(),
    unit = "relative",
    check = "equivalent",
    times = 50L
)
```

which gives

```
Unit: relative
 expr        min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   f1  1.0000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    50
   f2  4.1351785  4.099845  4.127982  4.088224  4.117141  3.649927    50
   f3  4.2296240  4.291979  4.842893  4.408095  4.817794 13.234459    50
   f4  0.9750334  0.979558  1.097199  1.010855  1.085660  1.760977    50
   f5 71.8225616 69.069376 64.921864 67.952181 64.960019 47.465078    50
```

and we can see that `lapply` or `rapply` with `%in%` should be the most efficient way, while `keep` is the least efficient.

Answer (score 1):

`purrr::keep()` in your example targets the top-level list. To target the nested
lists/vectors we need to iterate over the list with i.e. `lapply()` or `purrr::map()`.

Your example list did not include any of the target values so I sprinkled some
of those into `nested.list` in my example.

```r
library(purrr)
map(nested.list, keep, \(x) x %in% target.values)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 33514
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 193406
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> integer(0)
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1]  60369 193406
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> integer(0)
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 193406  60369
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 106408
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 106408
```